# Pivot table filtering based on a combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I would need your help in coding as I cannot figure out how to achieve it.
I wanted to link a combo box to influence the filtering of a pivot table but the coding I found cannot address what I want to achieve - i.e.

1) How could I link the pivot and combo box when they are on two different worksheet? - the combo box is in  Worksheet1 and the pivot is in Worksheet2.

2) How can I have the pivot to refresh the filter to "all" when the combo box (based on geographies) equivalent is "WW"?

The below code I found is a starting base but ended up with two errors.

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot_table1").PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=
    .List (.Value)
End With

End Sub
```

the Errors are the following: a)syntax error from the first line (I linked the macro to the combo box) and b) a compile error expected:expression on the activesheet.

Appreciate any hints on how to make it work - thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you use a slicer? It sounds as a slicer is what you are looking for. It's an "external" control of one or more pivot tables. Right click and insert slicer.

Comment: @Andreas, I do have Slicer for the other filtering, however, the lead control here for the geographies naming is a combo box, not only the pivot table. Hence the reason why I'm trying to update the pivot filtering based on a combo box and not the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an alternative solutions that worked out at the end - thanks all for watching and supporting.

```
Sub changeFilters()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim wsChart As Worksheet
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim SelGeo  As Variant

'turn on automatic update / calculation in the Pivot Table

Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data")
Set wsPivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot")
Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot").PivotTables("Pivot_table1")
Set SelGeo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data").Range("SelGeo")

pt.ManualUpdate = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCW_pivot").PivotTables("Pivot_table1").ClearAllFilters

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Data").Range("SelGeo") = WW Then
Exit Sub
End If

For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Geo").PivotItems
Select Case pi.Name
    Case [SelGeo]
        pi.Visible = True
        Case Else
        pi.Visible = False
    End Select
Next pi


'turn on automatic update / calculation in the Pivot Table

pt.ManualUpdate = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```